# Scroll-down to the search result page in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I started learning JavaScript a few days ago and I'm enjoying it so far.

Today I've been given a task where I need to add a scroll down function to an element when a button is clicked, but only if the screen width is less than or equal to 699 pixel. I've finished a webpage, and I just need to add the JavaScript for it.

This is the script snippet I have at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#button").click(function (){
        //$(this).animate(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#searchResult").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        //});
    });
});
```

And I need to add this:

```
if (screen.width <= 699)
```

How do I add the if statement to the script above? Also is there an easier way of doing this?

Thank you very much for your time,

Comment: wrap it around the animate-call like the commented-out animate-lines .. if(screen.width<=699){ $('html,body')...2000); } - No really easier way comes to mind, since you need to remind yourself it may be your script is running on a tablet where the orientation may change and suddenly a pre-calculated value of screen.width might become outdated, rechecking every click is neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function (){
var screenWidth = $(window).width();
    $("#button").click(function (){
        if (screenWidth <= 699){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#searchResult").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
        //other stuff your button does on all views
    });
});
```

I recommend setting mobile to 480px and tablet to 768px.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var width = $(window).width();
if(width < 699) {
//your script
}
```